# IBM MQ service on Windows not starting

Tags: ibm-mq

What's the difference of amqsvc and strmqsvc?

I have installed IBM MQ and configured for multi instance. It uses amqsvc.exe to start the service as installed, the service is logon from a domain account, and the account is a member of group mqm. 
It was working fine but yesterday for some unknown reason the service is not starting properly, here is what happened:

when amqsvc is run on automatic or manual, amqzxma0 runs on full cpu usage until timeout and windows prompted the service not starting with error 1053, but the MQ service is started, then I tried to start the queue manager but fail to start, however it can be started on interactive.

However I can start the service fine with strmqsvc and can start the queue manager normally. So what's the difference between these two and what is the problem behind it?

Comment: Please update on if the solution I provided fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`amqsvc` is the actual windows service.

`strmqsvc` is the command used to start the above service.

---

The [IBM v7.5 Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.mig.doc/q001510_.htm) documents the error 1053 as:

> **Windows: amqmsrvn.exe process removed**
>
> The amqmsrvn.exe DCOM process was replaced by a Windows service,
>   amqsvc.exe, in Version 7.1. This change is unlikely to cause any
>   problems. However, you might have to make some changes. You might have
>   configured the user that runs the IBM® WebSphere® MQ Windows service
>   MQSeriesServices without the user right to Log on as a service.
>   ***Alternatively, the user might not have List Folder privilege on all the subdirectories from the root of the drive to the location of the
>   service amqsvc.exe.***
>
> If you omitted the Log on as a service user privilege, ***or one of
>   the subdirectories under which IBM WebSphere MQ is installed does not
>   grant the List Folder privilege to the user, the MQ_InstallationName
>   IBM WebSphere MQ Windows services in Version 7.5 fails to start.***
>
> ...
>
> - If you did not give the user the List Folder privilege, the Windows Service Control Manager adds an event: 7009: Timed out waiting for the
>     service to connect. The strmqsvc command reports error 1053.

---

Ensure that you have provided List Folder privilege on all the subdirectories from the root of the drive to the location of the service amqsvc.exe.  This should resolve the issue.

Comment: the service account used to run the windows service is a domain account, and belongs to a domain group "domain mqm", and this "domain mqm" is a member of local mqm, so this service account should have full access to the mq directory.

Comment: also the service account has "Log on as a service" privilege as well

Comment: @Xstaci "Should have full access" and checking to see if the permission is in place are two different things. The error is clearly documented. The permission is needed on each directory from the ``\`` directory all the way down to the directory where `amqsvc.exe` is located. I think the permission was probably removed from a higher level directory some time before you noticed the issue.

Comment: @Xstaci did you check the directory structure permission? Were you able to resolve your problem?

Comment: It was not the directory structure permission, I've checked this one and has the exact same directory structure permission as another working environment. However the queue manager and all it's content has been deleted and rebuilt so I cannot investigate anymore, now it's all working. Thanks for the followup JoshMc.