# Unable to start message queue server

Tags: ibm-mq

When I start the Messaging queue It shows:

> ```
> Windows could not start the IBM MQ (Installation1) service on local
> computer.
>
> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control
> request in a timely fashion.
> ```

From the queue manager when I create with this code:

```
Command: "C:\DATA\TEMP\SoftwareInstallation\bin\crtmqm"  -sa  test
```

The following error occurs:

> ```
> AMQ7257S: The MQ service for installation 'Installation1'
> (C:\DATA\TEMP\SoftwareInstallation) must be running.
>
> exitvalue = 74
> ```

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47464751/ibm-mq-service-on-windows-not-starting/47465817#47465817

Comment: This link to may help: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/277644/amq7257-the-mq-service-must-be-running-to-perform/

Answer (score 0):

The second error your are getting is because, unless the IBM MQ service is running, nothing related to it works. As far as the issue with the service not coming up is concerned it is to do with the windows account through which you are trying to start the service.

You can refer the below link to find a fix,

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/886695/you-receive-an-error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or